# MySQL Cursor: looping through multiple rows? Getting 42000 error, "more than one row" - but expect multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, fetch

I thought the point of a cursor was to loop through multiple rows that match the criteria in the SQL used to define the cursor.

So I am baffled that I am getting this error when executing this code, as my goal IS to operate and extract key pieces of data from multiple rows matching a type of "Defense Contractor":

The error is the "Code: 1172 SQL State: 42000 --- Result consisted of more than one row"

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `clientschema`.`MapDistrictsToAccounts`()
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
 declare finished integer default 0;
 declare v_CD  varchar(45) default null;
 declare v_SSD varchar(45) default null;
 declare v_SHD varchar(45) default null;
 /* Temporary variable */
 declare v_sfdcDistrictId varchar(45) default null;
 declare v_sfdcAccountId varchar(45) default null;

 declare account_cursor cursor for
        select externalsys_id, congressional_district, state_house_district, state_senate_district from clientschema.Account where type="Defense Contractor";

/* declare not found handler*/
declare continue handler
for not found set finished = 1;

 open account_cursor;

 get_districts : LOOP
     fetch account_cursor into v_sfdcAccountId, v_CD, v_SHD, v_SSD;

      if finished = 1 THEN
      leave get_districts;
      end if;

     /* First do congressional district */
     select externalsys_id from clientschema.District where district_number__c = v_CD into v_sfdcDistrictId;
     /*if v_sfdcDistrictId = null then iterate get_districts;*/
     insert into clientschema.Account_Junction_District (district_id,hospital_idHospital,district_type__c) values (v_sfdcDistrictId, v_sfdcAccountId, "Direct");

     /* Next do State House district */
     select externalsys_id from clientschema.District where district_number__c = v_SHD into v_sfdcDistrictId;
     /*if v_sfdcDistrictId = null then iterate get_districts;*/
     insert into clientschema.Account_Junction_District (district_id,hospital_idHospital,district_type__c) values (v_sfdcDistrictId, v_sfdcAccountId, "Direct");

     /* Last do State Senate district */
     select externalsys_id from clientschema.District where district_number__c = v_SSD into v_sfdcDistrictId;
     /*if v_sfdcDistrictId = null then iterate get_districts;*/
     insert into clientschema.Account_Junction_District (district_id,hospital_idHospital,district_type__c) values (v_sfdcDistrictId, v_sfdcAccountId, "Direct");

     END LOOP get_districts;
close account_cursor;

END
```

Comment: ar which line number the error occurs? It seems to be a "select... into" returning more than one row.

Comment: Yes, Lucio, it is the  

`select externalsys_id, congressional_district, state_house_district, state_senate_district from clientschema.Account where type="Defense Contractor";`

I am expecting to process multiple rows where the type matches "Defense Contractor", and associate the districts to that contractor.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, except that for some reason, I can only select one row into those variables, and I'm not sure how to get at just the one row at a time?

Comment: "I am expecting to process multiple rows" then you must use a cursor for that select.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of "account_cursor"

Comment: Never mind. The problem was not the cursor. It was the district select. I did not put district type qualifier on the district select, and multiple districts were matching. Like, anything from 1-40 would return 2 rows. I have fixed my LOGIC.  Thank you Lucio.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was not the cursor.  it was a logic error.

the problem was the three queries like this:

`select externalsys_id from clientschema.District where district_number__c = v_CD into v_sfdcDistrictId;`

I needed to put a qualifier on the district type.  there are duplicate district numbers across the multiple district types.

problem solved!